# Is it possible? $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$

> Is it possible?
>   $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$

Comment: In general, you can find those limits using L'Hôpital https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule, as long as the limit after differentiating both sides exists. As has been demonstrated below, it is indeed possible, and in fact, its possible for all other reals on the RHS as well as infinity.

Comment: Take $g(x)=f(x)$. Easily you get limit $1$ of a fraction as $x$ approaches to $\infty$.

Comment: @UDAYPATEL The question was if the limit of the fraction can be $0$.

Comment: @SahibaArora Yes , it is definitely possible for getting limit $0$.

Answer (score 3):

As an example:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}, g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$

Generally, if the growth of the $f(x)$ towards $0$ is faster than $g(x)$, can be a good candidate for the case. However, you should consider each case by case.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = a$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = b$


 Is it possible?
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$

Comment: If $b\neq 0$, then $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{a}{b}$

Comment: Is it definetly true? Generally, if the growth of the $f(x)$ towards $0$ is faster than $g(x)$, limit equal to $0$??

Answer (score 3):

Assume $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0=\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ can be each element in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\pm\infty$ or it might doesn't exists!

**Example 1:** Define
$$
f(x)=\sin\left(\frac1x\right)~\text{ and }~g(x)=\frac{1}{ax}
$$
where $0\neq a\in\mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary number.
We compute
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{f\left(\frac1{x}\right)}{g\left(\frac1x\right)}=\lim_{x\to 0+}a\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=a.
$$
**Example 2:** Define
$$
f(x)=e^{-x}~\text{ and }~g(x)=\frac1x.
$$
We compute
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{-x}=0.
$$
**Example 3:** Define
$$
f(x)=\frac1{\pm x}~\text{ and }g(x)=\frac1{x^2}.
$$
We compute
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\pm x=\pm\infty
$$
**Example 4:** Define
$$
f(x)=\frac1{x}~\text{ and }~g(x)=\frac1{\cos(x)x}.
$$
We see that 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos(x)
$$
doesn't exists.

Comment: @OmG Generally, if the growth of the $f(x)$ towards $0$ is faster than $g(x)$, limit equal to $0$ İs it definitely true??

Answer (score 0):

For sure. In general, let $f,g$ be two real functions defined in an interval of the form $(a,+\infty)$ and let us suppose that:
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$
This means that, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an $M>0$, such that:
$$x>M\Rightarrow\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|<\epsilon$$
or, equivalently:
$$x>M\Rightarrow\left|f(x)\right|<\epsilon|g(x)|$$
Explaining that last equation, as, $\epsilon\to0$ - and especially, as $\epsilon$ gets smaller than $1$ - it means that $f$ is "finally" - by that meaning as $x\to+\infty$ - relatively "smaller" than $g$, hence enforcing the fraction $\frac{f}{g}$ get diminished to zero.

In our case, where $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=0$, it means that $f$ has to converge to $0$ "faster" than $g$.

Let us investigate now what "faster" means.

Let $\epsilon>0$, again. Due to conergence of both $f$ and $g$ to zero, there exist $A,B>0$, such that:
$$x>A\Rightarrow|f(x)|<\epsilon$$
$$x>B\Rightarrow|g(x)|<\epsilon$$
Let now $N=\max\{A,B,M\}$. Then, we have:
$$x>N\Rightarrow|f(x)|<\epsilon|g(x)|<\epsilon\cdot\epsilon=\epsilon^2$$
and 
$$x>N\Rightarrow|g(x)|<\epsilon$$
For $\epsilon\to0^+$, we have that $\epsilon^2<<\epsilon$, so "finally", for a given $\epsilon>0$, we can ensure a much tighter bound for $|f|$ than for $|g|$ - $\epsilon^2$ compared to $\epsilon$.

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: Absolutely help me!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You' re wellcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a well-known limit from high school which illustrates this:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}x = 0$$
which is the basis to prove the derivative of $\cos x$ is $-\sin x$.